# SMS Broadcast Receiver in Oreo+

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am trying to intercept SMS messages delivered to my device. I wrote an app to do that a year or so ago, and I find it is no longer catching messages (even though code is unchanged).

I don't believe it is permission-related. I tried compiling under SDK 23 (requiring runtime permissions) and SDK 22 (no runtime permissions). (In the case of 23, I verified that permission RECEIVE_SMS is successfully granted).

Most questions/answers about this issue are quite old. IMHO The answers didn't seem enlightened, e.g. adding BROADCAST_SMS permission, invoking native code, etc.

My approach was to implement a broadcast receiver. Code excepts below.

BROADCAST RECEIVER

```
//  SmsRecv.java - SMS Receiver    

package com.ramrod.SmsReceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SmsRecv extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //@ Handler for received sms messages
    @Override
    public void onReceive(
        Context ctx,
        Intent intent)
    {    
        // NEVER REACHED!
        Main.toast( "SMS RECEIVED." );
        // PROCESS MESSAGE HERE...    
    }
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.ramrod.SmsReceiver"
      android:versionCode="100"
      android:versionName="1.00">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:label="SmsReceiver"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
    >
      <activity android:name=".Main"
            android:label="SmsReceiver"
          >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <receiver android:name=".SmsRecv"
          android:exported="true"
          android:enabled="true"
          >
          <intent-filter android:priority="999999" >
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

BUILD.GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ramrod.SmsReceiver"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    ...
```

Tested on Samsung S7 running Oreo V8.0.0. I tested this by sending text messages from another phone. These were received correctly but never triggered SmsRecv().

In my reading, I encountered the notion that *now* an SMS broadcast receiver will no longer work unless it is the default SMS app on the device (huh?).

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I verified that permission RECEIVE_SMS is successfully granted" – How did you verify that, exactly? And which specific Android version did you test on? "I encountered the notion that now an SMS broadcast receiver will no longer work unless it is the default SMS app on the device" – Nah, as long as you have the permission, and an appropriate Receiver setup, you can still get the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast, barring any manufacturer-specific restrictions. That `Main.toast( "SMS RECEIVED." );` looks rather suspect. Why don't you just `Toast` in `onReceive()`, or better yet, log print or breakpoint?

Comment: Verified permission in my onRequestPermissionsResult() method. Also checked in Settings->Apps->SmsReceiver->Permissions. I tested on Oreo V8.0.0.

Comment: Main.toast is just a convenience wrapper around Toast (it works). I did set a breakpoint which was never reached. In one try, I did try Log.i() but nothing output.

Comment: Well, that wrapper needs a valid `Context`, and if that's coming from some static members in an `Activity`, it's rather fragile. Anyhoo, starting with Oreo, you have to explicitly request each individual permission that you use; i.e., you must explicitly request the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission at runtime in order to be delivered that broadcast. Just requesting `READ_SMS`, for example, no longer works. Are you specifically requesting `RECEIVE_SMS`? Also, are you testing this on an emulator, or a physical device? If the latter, which manufacturer is it?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you had edited your device model into the question. I have an S7 running 8.0, and can verify that you should have no problem receiving SMS, as long as you've got everything set up correctly.

Comment: Now, only specifically request RECEIVE_SMS (other perms were for future). Still no joy. Don't know where to go next...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199021/discussion-between-dontpanic-and-mike-m).

Comment: I left some messages in the chat room.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong. Apparently, Android version Oreo+ does not deliver **implicit** broadcasts any more* (i.e., those specified in the manifest file  <receiver>). You now must explicitly register your receiver (i.e., with **registerReceiver()**) in your code.

(*Note: Mike M correctly pointed out that received SMS broadcasts are excluded from this restriction according to Android doc, but nonetheless this was not so for me in practice).

So what I did to make this work was:

- Completely Remove <receiver> from manifest.
- Create an instance of my receiver and an intentFilter in my activities onCreate();

  ```
      MyReceiver = new SmsRecv();
      MyFilter   = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION );
  ```
- Register the receiver in my Activity's onResume().

  ```
      i = registerReceiver( MyReceiver, MyFilter);
  ```
- Unregister the receiver in my Activity's onPause(). (This is neccessary to prevent leaks).

  ```
      unregisterReceiver( MyReceiver );
  ```

With the changes, the app worked perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not correct for `SMS_RECEIVED`. It's on the list of broadcasts that are exempt from those restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions. I left a link in the chat room to a complete example, with the Receiver registered in the manifest, and I guarantee it works on Oreo (barring manufacturer-specific restrictions). Also, implicit broadcasts don't really have anything to do with where you register a Receiver. It's about how the broadcast `Intent` is constructed.

Comment: Well, I dunno. All I can say is that the registerReceiver method works perfectly for me, but the manifest <receiver> approach doesn't. I see your point that SMS_RECEIVED is supposedly exempt, but that's not applicable (for me) in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code but I've got a working solution now and I've already spent way too much time beating my head against the wall :)

Comment: @DontPanic, Hi, I am also looking for a similar solution. But are you able to receive broadcast when you minimize the app? Because I see you unregister the receiver as soon as you minimize the app.